# Validating a finite state machine (using AASM) on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fsm, aasm

I'm using [AASM by Rubyist](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/tree/master) to build a 4-step wizard for an AR object. According to the state of the object, there are different validations that need to be done. What is the smartest way to validate an object according to it's state on a certain transition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `:if` option, and `with_options` to bunch 'em together.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options :if => proc {|r| r.signup_step > 2 } do |o|
    o.validates_presence_of :title
    o.validates_presence_of :yeah
  end
end
```

What exactly you ought to write in the if-proc depends on your implementation, obviously.